# Is there a way to reverse engineer an existing schema into Liquibase?

Tags: liquibase

We have an existing schema created the old fashioned way with raw SQL.  I'd like to reverse engineer in to  Liquibase change set.  Is there any easy way to do that?

Regards,
Prakash

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. This is documented in the Liquibase documentation ["Starting Liquibase on an existing project"](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/existing_project.html)

You want to use the 'make it look like you've always used Liquibase' method, which basically involves using the `generateChangeLog` command. Note that there may be things in your database that Liquibase does not fully support, depending on your database platform. If you discover that there are many things like that, you may want to look into Datical DB, a commercial offering that uses Liquibase as its core engine, but which extends it quite a bit. I am one of the lead developers on that product.